# How to Identify the GitHub URL of a Cloned Git Repository Using Git Command?

Tags: git, github

I have a Git repository containing a folder with Git files, but I'm not certain if the repository was cloned from a specific URL on GitHub.

Is there a Git command that can help me identify the URL that the repository was cloned from, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a Git command that can help you identify the URL that the repository was cloned from. The command is called git remote show.

Run this command:

```
git remote show
```

This will tell you if the repository was cloned or not. If it was cloned from a URL it will show `origin`

Then you can see the URL by running :

```
git remote show origin
```

Comment: It means that it was not cloned from a remote repository